# Persistent GUID using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, guid

I need to **uniquely** identify machines visiting my website by installing a Local Shared Object in them, and also **persistently**, meaning that should a user delete the .sol file, another Local Shared Object will be created but with the same GUID in it upon visiting my website again.

All ActionScript samples I found on Google satisfy the uniqueness, but not the persistency as they use a timestamp as one seed factor of the GUID. Omitting that factor (timestamp) would probably influence the uniqueness of the GUIDs created.

I found an ActionScript that also incorporates the method Capabilities.serverString to maximize the uniqueness, but I sense it would also influence in a negative manner the persistence should one or more of the capability properties of the machine (hasMP3, hasPrinting, etc...) change.

So, what is the best approach to create a unique and persistent across deletions GUID?

Comment: Note that while it might be possible to implement this, most web apis are explicitly designed to avoid this. Using this in a public website without user consent might even be illegal in some parts of the world.

Comment: This is the answer most of the times was given to people asking how they could get through AS3 the mac address of their visitors' NICs. I don't care about their MAC address in particular. I want to be able to create an ID that will be persistent for the same machine and unique among other machine IDs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to achieve this with pure ActionScript or JavaScript I'm afraid, and it falls on the persistence (Without being able to read the MAC address or HDD serial number you don't have much to work with in terms of generating a GUID reliably).

Please note that even if you *could* generate a GUID that would meet your criteria, it could be spoofed (like anything client-side) and thus not be very useful for anything important server-side (assuming it was going to be sent to the server).

Comment: Think of the following scenario:

You have a community with members. Each member of course has a username and a password. But sneaky members can create multiple accounts from the same machine.

What I'm building is an app that, upon the first logging in of the member, will install an LSO with a (ideally persistent) GUID on his machine. Then, the forum script will read that GUID, and write it in the members table in a new field for that member.

Comment: When a sneaky member creates a second account from the same machine, the script will write the same GUID (which will read from the LSO) to the field of that member account.

In this way, an admin will easily track down duplicate accounts. What I need persistence for is that ideally I'd like the app to provide stats about how many different machines visit the forum.

Comment: I.e. I have an account in a forum with that app, and I use 3 different machines. So, in members table for my record, will be written down 3 different GUIDs (one for each machine). Now, if I accidentally (or intentionally) erase the LSO, or even re-format my machine, the flash movie will write another LSO with a GUID, that if it's not created in a persistent way, will be a different one, so the GUIDs in my record will become 4, thus ruining the stats...

Comment: Got it. I think the best you can hope for is storing a GUID that is unique in a LSO and hope users won't delete it. Most users don't know how to delete a LSO (of course there are tools for it) or even know that they exist, so the percentage that will delete it is probably very low.

Comment: I'd still rather not rely on luck...

There must be a way to produce a persistent (and globally unique) ID for each machine, with it being reproducible every time it's needed to.

I just feel it's some kind of "secret" that the ones who know it, won't share with others!!! :P